# How do I make this table 0-9 with loops in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

How do I make this table?
This is what should be the outcome:

```
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                         
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
        2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
        3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
        4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
        5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
        6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
        7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
        9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

And this is the best I could come up with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

 {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (i + j < 10) {
                    System.out.print(i + j);
                } else
                    System.out.print("x");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

I simply can't find a solution how to get numbers running again past 9 with the beginning of 0,1,2,3 etc. My code would generate next:

```
        0123456789
        123456789x
        23456789xx
        3456789xxx  
        456789xxxx
        56789xxxxx
        6789xxxxxx 
        789xxxxxxx
        89xxxxxxxx
        9xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Using % (Modulo) like in the answer is the nicest way. But another simple way would be to substract 10 from the value in your else clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
System.out.print((i + j) % 10);
```

To turn `10` into `0`, `11` into `1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  for (int j=i; j<i+10; j++) {
    System.out.print(j%10);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

The key here is to use `%`(modulo) operator.